# Administrating CQ5 via command line NOT using cURL or wget

Tags: python, python-requests, aem

I'm trying to write a script for administrating CQ5 via command line NOT using cURL or wget.  When I try to upload a package I get the following error message:

`{"success":false,"msg":"package file parameter missing"}`

When using cURL everything works fine.  I looked at the header and body cURL sends and rebuilt both via python without success.  cURL doesn't seem to send a "file" parameter (or at least I didn't see it).

What file am I missing? How do I provide the missing file?

Comment: You may be interested in [CQ Unix Tools](https://github.com/Cognifide/CQ-Unix-Toolkit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using Ken Reitz's excellent [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library to do the HTTP requests (if not, you really should be!)

Most likely, the problem is that requests doesn't add a 'Content-type' header to multi-part uploads, and packmgr doesn't read multi-part bodies with no 'Content-type' header. So, while a normal 'requests' POST of a multipart-encoded file would go something like this:

```
url = 'http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json?cmd=upload'
files = {'package': open('package.zip', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

you instead have to use the longer form, setting an explicit content-type:

```
url = 'http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json?cmd=upload'
files = {'package': ('package.zip', open('package.zip', 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Note that one side-effect of doing it this way is that it cannot stream the file - the entire package ZIP file will be read into memory.